# how to get or set localStorage or sessionStorage storage using c#?

Tags: c#, javascript

I need to find a way to get or set data, to or from `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` using C#.
Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Directly no. They're both client side and only accessible through JavaScript they *never* end up being serialised back to the server where the C# runs.

However, you could use JavaScript and have it talk to the C# side using AJAX or some such.

Comment: Thank you, i know this option. i thought maybe there is a way to do it directly.

Comment: @AdamB Remember there's a disjoin between the C# execution on the web server and the rendering and JavaScript execution on the web browser. Cookies can be passed from browser to server with requests but not storage data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from JavaScript. refer below link for the same :

[Local Storage and Session Storage](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-20/localstorage-and-sessionstorage)